# Ajax request breaks response body?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm baffled trying to get this to work properly.
I'm using jQuery 1.10.3 to attempt retrieval of a JSON-encoded object. This request should normally be fulfilled by a php script, which (when visited directly) returns it correctly (at least, to the human eye).
However, when I use a jQuery request to fetch it, I end up with a ton of garbage that jQuery can't parse.
It looks like so:

```
��VQo�6~N�
```

When it should look like this:

```
{"227382":[{"id":"1593515742","type":"household",
```

What am I doing wrong here?

PHP source of the request proxy: http://pastebin.com/hYcb1L2Z
Line that inits the jQuery ajax request:
$.getJSON( "proxy.php?Action=GET&Url=https://somesite.com/getsomeJson&lang=eng" )

Comment: where is your code?? Please share it..

Comment: Show your jQuery call

Comment: It seems that it's encoding issue, check the encoding types the server and the client use.

Comment: Is that the extent of the JSON object?  It look incomplete as I see it which could be why you're having a hard time parsing it.

Comment: It's not the entirety of the JSON object, just an example of the difference. I have no idea how to set the encoding, as I thought I was just passing stuff from one server to the next, no encoding-decoding involved.

Comment: As a thought, I converted each character to a decimal value (so I could try and see what's behind the question marks), and found that there are a ton of characters numeral 65533. Didn't help though, I have no idea where these things are coming from...

Comment: Okay, just realized that I didn't pass the source server's headers properly, I think this may be the key, except now I'm getting an odd 500 error....

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the proxy.php script wasn't passing along the

```
Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
```

header. Fixed that and all is working much better!